# Radical identity proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Looking for **hints only** for a proof of

$$\operatorname{rad}\Biggl(\prod_{x=1}^{y}\gcd(x+y,x-y)\Biggr)=\Biggl(\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \left( -1 \right) ^{y+1}\Biggr)\operatorname{rad}(y)$$

where $\operatorname{rad}(n)$ is the radical of $n$

Comment: ah thanks for that it's $y$ sorry

Comment: A prime that divides both $x+y$ and $x-y$ divides $2y$.

Comment: ok thanks I'll see how I go

Comment: so do I start with $\gcd(x+y,x-y)=\gcd(x-y,2y)$?

Comment: omfg who keeps voting to close my questions

Comment: "omfg who keeps voting to close my questions "  Why would that surprise you?

Comment: @fleablood is it not frustrating for you that this action can be done without revealing the user identity and more importantly, without detailing  their perceived justification for the action?

Comment: I have no issue with being subject to criticism, this is a fundamental element of Stack Exchange, but I am not learning from a users negative appraisal of the content I present if it is not described in detail

Comment: I can't quite remember *why* I wrote that a month and a half ago but I think I was being somewhat sarcastic.  Downvoting for inexplicable reasons is so common here there's not really any point in being surprised.  Yes, it's frustrating ... but not surprising.  .... It helps to not care about your reputation.

Comment: no its the absence of context for the downvote I am missing here, reputation points don't mean much, but because I am not at a university, they are helpful in the sense that it's all I really have other than my own criticism

Comment: Sorry for the late response, there is a reason for that, but I'm not in the business of seeking pity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\textbf{Hint:}$
The $(-1)^{y+1}$ part motivates us to consider the cases when $y$ is odd and when it is even separately.rad() only extracts distinct prime factors.In addition we have the observation that,

$gcd(x+y,x-y)=gcd(x-y,2y)$.
What can you say from this?

$\textbf{Solution:}$
if $y$ is even.Then, we can extract from the L.H.S ,only the prime divisors of $y$
(taken only once). and since $x$ ranges from $1$ to $y$.we can surely extract all of them.
SO,left hand side is just $rad(y)$ in that case.

Similarly if $y$ is odd we can extract only $rad(n)$ and $2$ from the left hand side.

Comment: sure that was as far as I got yesterday. It tells us $\gcd(0,2y)$ is a term in the product, hence it's radical most certainly contains all the factors of the radical of $2y$, which is twice the radical of $y$ when $y$ is coprime with $2$ but yes I am still stuck on explaining the origin of the alternating component

Comment: So go by a two case scenario and substitute $y=2y'$ for one and $y=2y'+1$ for the other?

Comment: Well,you can argue more easily.

Comment: ok I'll accept if I keep asking for more I'm just being lazy

Comment: But saulspatz's hint is probably worth the vote tbh